# Get the string to the right of another string

Tags: php, strpos

Been working a bit on a chat/shoutbox of mine, and I have a row in my `users` table called `muted` (0 for not muted, 1 for muted). What I want to do is, when you type `!mute <target>` it should update the row with the `<target>` and set muted to 1.

I know how to check if a string contains !mute, which is like this:

```
if (strpos($sboxmsg,'!mute') !== false) {

}
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to get anything to the right of !mute. And I also need to turn everything to the right into a variable which I can use in a query later on.

Example:

```
!mute Nick
```

Then it would store Nick in a variable called eg. `$variable1`

Is this possible? All help is appreciated!

Comment: get the pos of the space, then `substr()` everything to the right of that, giving you the name

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$variable1 = preg_replace('/^\!mute\s+/', '', $whatever_input);
```

Comment: Seemed like the easiest solution. Thanks, it worked smoothly! Will mark this as the best answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You could explode on `!mute`:

```
$pieces = explode($sboxmsg, '!mute ');
$muted = (count($pieces) > 1);
if ($muted) {
    $muted_user = $pieces[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take the part of the string you want like this.

```
if (strpos($sboxmsg,'!mute') !== false) {
    $index = strpos($sboxmsg,'!mute'); //In index we save the start of '!mute'.
    $index = $index + 6; //Now we go to the end of '!mute '. Please note that here I also take the blank space.
    $mutedName = substr($sboxmsg, $index, strlen($sboxmsg) - $index); //We take from the original string, starting after '!mute'.
}
```

Now you have in `$mutedName`, Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (strpos($sboxmsg,'!mute') !== false) {

                $pieces = explode('!mute ', $sboxmsg);

                    if (count($pieces) > 1) {

                     $muted_user = $pieces[1];
                        $muted_value = 1

                     }
            }
```